# Modifier.wrapContentWidth() vs Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max) in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I want to create a [Column](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#column) which is as wide as the widest child [Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#text) inside it. For this purpose the column can use [`.wrapContentWidth()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#wrapcontentwidth) modifier or [`.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#width), but the result looks the same. What is the difference between these two modifiers? For example:

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth()
//  modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
) {
    Text("short text", Modifier.background(Color.LightGray))
    Text("some longer text", Modifier.background(Color.LightGray))
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary

Answer (score 18):

Let's add a [Divider](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#divider) between the texts. We want the divider to be as wide as the widest text.

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth()
//  modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
) {
    Text("short text", Modifier.background(Color.LightGray))
    Divider(color = Color.Red)
    Text("some longer text", Modifier.background(Color.LightGray))
}
```

[image]
[image]

As you see, in case of `Modifier.wrapContentWidth()` the divider forces the column to be as wide as its parent. It happens because `Divider` uses `.fillMaxWidth()` under the hood and since the column's `.wrapContentWidth()` doesn't constraint its children width, the divider expands as much as it can.

In the same time `Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)` behaves as we'd expected. The divider doesn't occupy space if no constraints are given, so it's intrinsic width is 0 and it doesn't affect the column width.

Comment: According to documentation, calling the `Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)` sizes its children being forced to be as wide as the maximum intrinsic width. How come the divider width becomes 0?